# Laravel migration unique still allowing the same entry

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table migration where I try to force validation of a phone_number field as unique:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->string('phone_number');
  $table->string('email')->nullable();
  $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
  $table->string('password');
  $table->string('user_type')->nullable();
  $table->boolean('is_admin');
  $table->rememberToken();
  $table->timestamps();

  $table->unique('phone_number');
});
```

However, when I try to create two users with the same phone_number (E.g. "27841231234"), it still allows it, and just assigned two different IDs to those...
Am I understanding the unique function incorrectly? And how can I force laravel to not allow two similar phone_numbers to be stored?

### EDIT:

Here is my MYSQL db structure, which also indicates that the field is picking up as unique, but still allowing duplicate values:

```
| Field             | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| phone_number      | varchar(255)        | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| email             | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email_verified_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password          | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_type         | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_admin          | tinyint(1)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| remember_token    | varchar(100)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at        | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at        | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: your code looks all right, what database do you use? could you check the database structure and properties?

Comment: the UNI property is there as shown in the edit. Its a MySQL database

Comment: you can also try $table->string('phone_number')->unique() but I doubt it would make a difference.

Comment: yeah, I have tried it to no avail =/

Comment: Can you insert the same phone number from the MySQL command line or tools like MySQLWorkbench as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

- $table->string('phone_number')->unique();

Instead of these two:

- $table->string('phone_number');
- $table->unique('phone_number');

At the end run this command:

- php artisan migrate

Hopefully you'll get your desire results.